# Including thousands of images in Xamarin Forms application

Tags: android, ios, image, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a xamarin forms project for the company I work for.  I have 6000+ images used in two ways : a thumbnail page and a full size page.  I have both the thumbnail image and the full size image.  The thumbnail page shows 12 products at a time, but it lives in a carousel page so it could have up to 18 content pages within the carousel.

I've tried three ways of saving/accessing the images:

1. Including them as bundle/android resources.  This works the best but takes forever to build the project and on android will mean I have to use expansion files.
2. Included the binary image from the database when downloading the product listing.  Causes the app to crash randomly on download.
3. Downloading all of the files from the web.  This works, but on both Android and iOS, the thumbnail screen slows to a crawl and half of the time crashes on Android.

Has anyone had to do something similar and if so, what way did you decide to go?  Unfortunately, this app does have to be usable offline so I need the images local.  I'm kind of in a time crunch so any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: If working offline is a hard-requirement, then using Android `.obb`s well be required, unless you are going to force the app's first time usage to download and cache those images. For app build times and testing, for the media elements in games, we create custom build scripts to include 'all' the files in full release builds as keeping that many files in your development `.csproj` is pure death to your debug cycles. Create a few media placeholders and use them in debug/testing cycles as there is no reason that as a developer I need to actually see and scroll through 6k catalog images.

Comment: @SushiHangover thank you for the reply!  I wanted to go down the obb path, but cannot find a good tutorial how to do that with Xamarin forms.  Do you have or have you seen anything to help me in that area?  Also, if you have an example build script I could view that would help me out a lot.  Thank you again!

Comment: As far as your #2/3 question, we would need to see some code & stack traces to help on app crashes as the actual process of downloading and/or displaying images would not be the cause, nor the number images, but your  implementation of those routines.

Comment: We are not using `.obb`s with Xammie Forms but I can not think of anything that would be 'special' in that case, resources are resources.... I see if I can release a few of of the scripts that we use to build the apk, obb, and ipa. We are in the 1GB range of 'external' media, mostly images, but lots of sound clips, binary shaders, serialized levels, etc...  also...

Comment: @SushiHangover thank you again.  I'm sitting in the 500-600 MB range right now.  I've never implemented obb's so I'm just not 100% sure how it all works and how I would access my images from it.  Thank you!

Comment: np, `.obb`s are 'just' zip files that are linked to your apk in the Store and updating your `.obb` requires updating your apk also (at the very least its version number). You do have to implement Play's Application Licensing service as that is required to use the downloader service. The `obb` itself is really simple, a zip with files, it is up to you to decide if you need to extract files from it (ones that are compressed) or use them in place (within the zip) but those files need to be non-compressed... (that is how we use them, a big single zip file of lots of non-compressed files...)

Comment: I'll give that a shot.  Thank you again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had similar issues someday back and understood that it won't be successful with standard `Image` class with such a large amount of images (no memory caching, no task queueing, etc). Then I made `CachedImage`. It's basically an API compatible replacement for `Image` with advanced caching capabilities (and some other features). You could try that.

Just remember to use:

- Downsampling feature : that way image would be resized to view size to save memory
- Caching feature (it's enabled by default not including `StreamImageSource` for which you have to provide custom cache key factory)
- Use `FileImageSource` (app dir) or `StreamImageSource` (eg. from image database) with custom cache keys
  https://github.com/molinch/FFImageLoading (See WIKI for docs)